# How to create a batch file that creates a batch file that creates a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a batch file called test1 that creates a batch file called test2 that creates a batch file called test3
I made this:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO ECHO > test3.bat > test2.bat
```

But it doesn't work.
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will have to escape special chars like `>`with a caret `^`

```
echo echo echo hello ^>t3.bat >t2.bat
type t2.bat
call t2.bat
type t3.bat
call t3.bat
```